# SQL Table to SQL Table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, transpose

I have a database table in the following format (populated via .net function, empties are blank, not NULL):

```
A             B        C       D 

Spoons        ID
              38483

Date          Amt      Value   Type
1/1/2017      2        12      Plastic
1/2/2017      4        30      Silver
1/3/2017      1        9       Wood
```

How can I write a stored procedure that will result in the following table?

```
Col1       Col2       Col3         Col4     Col5
----------------------------------------------------
Spoons     38483      1/1/2017     2        Plastic
Spoons     38483      1/2/2017     4        Silver
Spoons     38483      1/3/2017     1        Wood
```

Note: I am using SQL Server 2016

Comment: It's helpful to tag database questions with both the appropriate software (MySQL, Oracle, DB2, ...) and version, e.g. `sql-server-2014`. Differences in syntax and features often affect the answers. Have you tried anything? Done any research? Used a shiny [`create procedure`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-procedure-transact-sql) (assuming SQL Server)? Curious that you have one table that almost looks like a spreadsheet. Does it have any associated DDL?

Comment: Yea the table was/is originally a spreadsheet, but I converted to csv after determining that it couldn't be parsed via t-sql (or at least OPENROWSET and linked servers are not supported by the version I'm using. Then I used .net to insert into a sql table. I created the server in the Azure portal

Comment: So the table definition is `A VarChar(max), B VarChar(max), C VarChar(max), D VarChar(max)` with no order to the rows? Perhaps [this](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) will provide some pointers as to what's missing from your question.

Comment: Ahhh. Yes sorry, the rows are always in the order shown, and all data points are nvarchar(250)

Comment: Tables have no inherent order. Unless there is a way to apply an `order by`, e.g. an identity column, the rows are just sitting in a sack waiting to be plucked out. You're left with analyzing each row and column and trying to guess where it might fit in your desired output, e.g. if it doesn't look like a date in some format and it's in column `A` and it doesn't say "Date" then it must be the new `Col1` value.

Comment: You need to fix the spreadsheet before importing. That structure is a sure loser over time. Get rid of it and correctly format your spreadsheet.

Comment: @HABO - Ok so I will have a table that will list out all the Product Names (i.e. "Spoons") as well as another table that lists the ProductIDs (note that product names and product IDs are not related in this context)

HLGEM - Client says I can't alter the spreadsheet in any way because it is used by to many people and is generated by an app that can't be changed. All I'm trying to do is extract the data into a customizable table that I can work with

Comment: I'd like to lookup every value of column A in the Product Name table and if it matches, use the match as the product name for all rows in the new table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT LEAD ( [A], 1 ) OVER (ORDER BY [ID] asc) as Col1 FROM Table1    --- (Note I added an ID clmn) 

SELECT Top 1 LEAD ( [B], 2 ) OVER (ORDER BY [ID] asc) as Col2 FROM Table1 

SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [ID] asc) AS RowNumber, * FROM Table1 WHERE RowNumber BETWEEN x AND y
```

Then insert all that into a final table... Simple question = simple answer. I'm just relatively new to sql so it was difficult to figure out on my own.